# Other users aren't forced to login after successful login with nodejs + Express

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

I am looking to do a login only flow.

I am able to successfully authenticate, but when another user from a different device logs in, they aren't required to login in through Azure AD and immediately have access to the page. However when they navigate to auth/login it properly adopts to expected behavior.

I have middleware that checks for req.isAuthenticated, but it passes as it seems it has the token stored.

I used the example found at https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS

I am using the ODIC Strategy and using only id_token for the response assuming an Implicit flow.

When I try session: false it seems to loop over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Indicates the type of user interaction that is required.

Add `prompt=login` to the [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-the-sign-in-request) which **forces the user to enter their credentials** on that request, negating single-sign on.